# How to make a Labels array public

Tags: c#, arrays, forms, label, public

```
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        palabras pala = new palabras();
        pala.Traelo();
        Label[] labels = new Label[pala.cantLetras];

   }
 private void MoveteA()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < posActLabelsX.Count; i++)
        {
         labels[i].Location=Point(posLabelFormX - posLabelBotonX, posLabelFormY - posLabelBotonY);   
        }
    }
```

But  it won't let me use it cause it's not public but if I put public  Label[] labels = new Label[pala.cantLetras]; it gives me an error that I don't know what is but breaks the whole program.

Comment: Make it a global field?

Comment: Can you put the error that gives you when you put labels public?

Comment: You generally shouldn't do that.  Labels are GUI elements that are the responsibility of the form.  It's probably better to just create a public function or method that accesses or processes that text information for you.  It looks like you are trying to mimic what the FlowLayoutPanel does.

Answer (score 0):

public fields can be put directly inside your class like so

```
public Label[] labels;
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    palabras pala = new palabras();
    pala.Traelo();
    labels = new Label[pala.cantLetras];
}
```

however, if you don't use it outside your class, you might be able to keep it private yet, and you'll still be able to use it in both methods, since they're both in your class

Answer (score 0):

I would create a public get property , and a private set like this :

```
    public Label[] labels {get; private set;}
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        palabras pala = new palabras();
        pala.Traelo();
        labels = new Label[pala.cantLetras];
   }
```

also you boundary in the for loop can cause an Index out of bounds, fix it like this :

```
for (int i = 0; i < labels.Count; i++)
```